# Next.js NPM error when running 'npm run dev'

Tags: linux, node.js

I’m following a tutorial on: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started/setup

Currently I’ve followed all instructions and have run into a problem when I type in `npm run dev` in my terminal – just wondering if anybody else has encountered this issue, and what the solution might be.

[image: error log in I'm seeing in terminal currently]

Advice or guidance in resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: `grep -1 -F 16.8.6 package.json`

Comment: post your `package.json` file.